# on run argv and other handlers

Tags: applescript

I'm pretty new to applescript and I can't get past the point of accepting arguments from the command line. I've read that I can do it like this:

```
on run argv
    log "SOMETHIG
end run

on readLines(unixPath)
    set targetFile to (open for access (POSIX file unixPath))
    set fileText to (read targetFile for (get eof targetFile) as text)
    set fileLines to every paragraph of fileText

    close access targetFile
    return fileLines
end readLines
```

The problem is that it doesn't let me define `on run argv` together with other functions (or handlers) define with `on` while it lets me define any number of funciona (apart from `on run argv`). How come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
on run
    log "Something"
end run
```

and

```
log "Something"
```

do the same thing. The first script has an explicit run handler while the second, an implicit run handler. A script object can only have one run handler.

This script would not work because you can't have a handler inside a handler

```
on run 
    log "SOMETHIG"

    on readLines(unixPath)
        set targetFile to (open for access (POSIX file unixPath))
        set fileText to (read targetFile for (get eof targetFile) as text)
        set fileLines to every paragraph of fileText
        close access targetFile
        return fileLines
    end readLines

end run
```

However you can define a handler outside "on run" and call it from within:

```
on run
    log "Something"
    readLines("/Users/pistacchio/Desktop/test.txt")
end run

on readLines(unixPath)
    set targetFile to (open for access (POSIX file unixPath))
    set fileText to (read targetFile for (get eof targetFile) as text)
    set fileLines to every paragraph of fileText

    close access targetFile
    return fileLines
end readLines
```

Alternatively, you can simply use the implicit run handler:

```
log "Something"
readLines("/Users/pistacchio/Desktop/test.txt")

on readLines(unixPath)
    set targetFile to (open for access (POSIX file unixPath))
    set fileText to (read targetFile for (get eof targetFile) as text)
    set fileLines to every paragraph of fileText

    close access targetFile
    return fileLines
end readLines
```